# Page hangs when leaving it for a while using ASP.NET Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I'm working on a business application using ASP.NET Ajax , NHibernate and Spring.Net, I've got an annoying problem. The problem is that when I leave page for about 5 minutes and then return back and try to make any action that posts back, it displays wrongly (if there are controls hidden by style it became visible). In addition, the page didn't post back to the server.

Also the problem happens when opening two different tabs, different pages (Each page uses session but different keys )

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As you describe the problem, its sounds that connect the content of the page with the user cookie and session, and when the session expired the application did not take care to recreate it.

So the post back fail because the session data have been lost when the page ask for them / need them to work and display correct the results.

This is the issue that I diagnose, how you fix that is up to you :)

### Possible solutions

1. Change the logic of the page creation.
2. While the user is on page do not let the session ends (not good practice)
3. Store the user data of the page, on a database - connected with the user, and delete it after some days if not have been updated.

Comment: thanks Aristos, I cannot understand which session are you talking about, do you mean Server session or what, also i cannot guess how to change the logic of page creation

Comment: @GHOST Yes server session that is connect with the user.

Comment: I think it is not a server session issue because the page doesn't post back to the server

Comment: @GHOST do you read what you write ? "...and try to make any action that posts back..."